# Get native SQL from QueryDSL JPA (JPAQuery or JPQLQuery)

Tags: jpa, jpql, querydsl

I have a requirement to count the number of group by records for pagination purpose. For example:

```
select count(*) from ( 
    select name, count(id) from customer
    group by name
);
```

However it couldn't be achieved via QueryDSL due to the limitation of JPA 
where JPQL doesn't allows to select count from sub query.

Is it possible to get the native SQL from QueryDSL JPAQuery or JPQLQuery? My plan  is to construct and execute the select count native SQL statement via EntityManager.

```
String subQueryNativeSQL = "..."; // native SQL from QueryDSL
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select count(*) from (" + subQueryNativeSQL + ")");
long count = (long) q.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Of course JPQL allows you to select COUNT in a subquery, as per the JPA spec. `simple_select_expression::= single_valued_path_expression | scalar_expression | aggregate_expression | identification_variable`

Comment: Hi Neil, May be you can show me on how to use JPQL to construct the SQL statement I posted above?

Comment: maybe you can post your ENTITIES and what you have tried with JPQL first. Because JPQL clearly depends on classes/fields and you post none of them

Comment: The title (what I'm looking for) has no relation with the actual question. Pls update.

Answer (score 2):

Both `JPAQuery` and `JPQLQuery` implement [`Projectable`](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.6.1/apidocs/com/mysema/query/Projectable.html#count()) interface and implement `count()` method - and you ain't need subqueries